# How to query multiple fields in an academic database that only lets one query the fields separately?

Tags: literature-search, scopus, web-of-science, pubmed

PubMed's [tiab] (citation's title, collection title, abstract, other abstract and author keywords) or WoS's TS (Title, Abstract, Author Keywords, Keywords Plus®) field codes are very useful but I couldn't find anything about how to perform similar queries on other databases such as EBSCOHost, ProQuest, Wiley Online Library etc. which only lets one query the fields separately.

For example, I want to find papers that contain both "titanium" and "parkinson*" in the combined text of their titles, abstracts, and keywords. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi. Each of these platforms are independent and unique, so I don't think you will find a one-fits-all solution. However, if any of these provide API access I'd bet that you can do your search through it. Maybe you should make your question more focused.

Comment: Go find your friendly, often forgotten, local research librarian to help you learn the tools available at your institution. They are experts in finding things - use their expertise.

Comment: I recommend you to write your comment as an answer, even if it only applies to only one platform. People can build up upon your answer and it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer by a little bit of tinkering. Let's say I want to search two terms across three fields, then the logic is:

```
(field_code_1 (term_1) OR field_code_2 (term_1) OR field_code_3 (term_1))
AND
(field_code_1 (term_2) OR field_code_2 (term_2) OR field_code_3 (term_2))
```

This gives both terms the freedom to be anywhere in the specified field codes, then joins both conditions with the AND operator. Therefore, following our example, if I want to find papers that contain both "titanium" and "parkinson*" in the combined text of their titles, abstracts, and keywords/subject terms, I can query EBSCOHost with a string like below:

```
(TI(titanium) OR AB(titanium) OR SU(titanium)) AND (TI(parkinson*) OR AB(parkinson*) OR SU(parkinson*))
```

**Note:** For this approach to work, the interface must have properly functioning Boolean operators, parentheses, and field codes.

I also validated this logic by comparing the results of these queries and seeing that they are the exact same:

**Web of Science:**

1. `(TI=(titanium) OR AB=(titanium) OR AK=(titanium) OR KP=(titanium)) AND (TI=(parkinson*) OR AB=(parkinson*) OR AK=(parkinson*) OR KP=(parkinson*))`
2. `TS=(titanium AND parkinson*)`

**Scopus:**

1. `TITLE(titanium) OR ABS(titanium) OR KEY(titanium) AND TITLE(parkinson*) OR ABS(parkinson*) OR KEY(parkinson*)`
2. `TITLE-ABS-KEY(titanium AND parkinson*)`